# When a StreamSubscription is paused; are events buffered or dropped?

Tags: dart

The [`StreamSubscription`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.StreamSubscription#id_pause) class has a `pause()` method. The docs don't indicate whether events are buffered while a stream is paused (and then all fired once resumed), or dropped; which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `StreamSubscription` is always expected to buffer events while it is paused.
It may pass the pause state on to its source to avoid being swamped, but even if it can't, it will buffer data until it runs out of memory.

For a broadcast stream, where events are typically not part of a greater whole, you might not want the events. In that case you can cancel the subscription and create a new one when you need events again. Broadcast streams should generally allow resubscribing after a cancel, but some may have been set up in such a way that it isn't possible, e.g., by dropping its resources after the last client cancels.

For a single subscription stream, where events are often a sequence of chunks of a bigger thing, dropping events should probably never happen.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Do you happen to know which bug is tracking the DOM behaviour mentioned in my answer?

Comment: As explained above, broadcast streams will not buffer but single subscription stream will

Comment: The subscription will always buffer when paused, it doesn't matter which kind of stream it comes from, single-subscription, broadcast or the newer multi-cast (from `Stream.multi`).

Answer (score 0):

The docs also include this text:

> Currently DOM streams silently drop events when the stream is paused. This is a bug and will be fixed.

This suggests that intention is that events will be buffered and then released once you unpause. If you wish not to receive the events during this period, you are best cancelling and resubscribing.

Comment: A link to the issue would be great.

Comment: I did search, but couldn't find it in the tracker; i could only find a commit that added this line to the docs, but there was no bug number :(

Comment: This looks related but already fixed 8/2013 http://dartbug.com/9700 This http://dartbug.com/10201 is for broadcast streams where it is not supported and the issue was closed as `WontFix`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Neither of those appear DOM-related, but the note in the docs specifically says for DOM events :( [Here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/detail?r=30122) is the commit that added the note.

Comment: You are right, I forgot about that because the question doesn't contain it.

Comment: The question wasn't about DOM events; but the wording of this note suggested the answer (since it wouldn't be unusual for DOM streams to work this way if it was intended that they'd be dropped) :)